# Is it possible to substitute the limit value of an SQL query with some input coming from html form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, random

This is my query:
SELECT * FROM learning_assessment.tbl_qna order by rand() limit 10;

---

tbl_qna is my table for questions. What I wanted to happen is to substitute the limit value "10" to a number coming from an input of the admin.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
Number of questions: <br>
<input type="text" name="numQ"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Number of Questions to Generate"  name="save"></input>
</form>
```

Is it possible to get the input value from

---

```
<input type="text" name="numQ"></input>
```

and substitute it to my query limit value (10) , so that the user could generate his desired number or questions like 50 or 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use a parameter

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM learning_assessment.tbl_qna order by rand() limit :limit;")
$sth->bindParam(":limit",$_POST['numQ'],PDO:PARAM_INT);
$result = $sth->execute();
```

I'm most comfortable with PDO, but you can do the same with MySQLi